# Using 2D arrays as multiple 1D arrays when using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I used the below program to access 2D arrays using pointers.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

void main()
{

  int num[3][2]={ {00,01},{10,11},{20,21} }; 
  int i,j;
  printf("-----------------------------------");
  /* Treating 2d array as 1d array of each row */
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
        printf("\nThe Address(&num[%d]) is %u \n \n<= WHICH IS THE SAME AS =>\n \n(num[%d]) %u \t",i,&num[i],i,num[i]);
        printf("[*(num+%d)] %u \t [(num+%d)] %u ",i,*(num+i),i,(num+i)); 
        printf("\n The Value is %d \n",*num[i]);
        printf("\n -----------------------------------");
  }
}
```

And this is the Output:

```
    -----------------------------------
The Address(&num[0]) is 2140353424 

<= WHICH IS THE SAME AS =>

(num[0]) 2140353424     [*(num+0)] 2140353424    [(num+0)] 2140353424 
 The Value is 0 

 -----------------------------------
The Address(&num[1]) is 2140353432 

<= WHICH IS THE SAME AS =>

(num[1]) 2140353432     [*(num+1)] 2140353432    [(num+1)] 2140353432 
 The Value is 10 

 -----------------------------------
The Address(&num[2]) is 2140353440 

<= WHICH IS THE SAME AS =>

(num[2]) 2140353440     [*(num+2)] 2140353440    [(num+2)] 2140353440 
 The Value is 20 

 -----------------------------------
```

I understood what happens in the program and I know that `*(num+i)` is used to access each row's address.

**But, why both `*(num+i)` and `(num+i)` point to the same address?**

To access the value at that particular row (i'th row) we use `**(num+i)` which makes sense because `*(num+i)` points to the 1st 1D array's row's address and we can use another indirection operator to dereference that pointer.

But how come both `*(num+i)` and `(num+i)` point to the same address? 
Is this compiler dependent? Or some undefined behavior?

Please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: where is the problem? it is ok, *(num + i) = (num + i)[0] and *((num + i)[0]) = num[i][0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays are stored contiguously in memory. Here's a memory layout of your array:

```
 [0][0] [0][1] [1][0] [1][1] [2][0] [2][1]
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  00  |  01  |  10  |  11  |  20  |  21  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|_____________|_____________|_____________|
^             ^             ^
num[0]        num[1]        num[2]
```

On my machine int has size of 4 bytes. 
`num` has type `int (*)[2]` - it is a pointer to array of 2 ints. Statement `num+1` is a pointer arithmetic and results in adding 8 bytes (that's the size of two ints) to the address where `num` array begins. 
After dereference - `*(num+1)` it is still a pointer and it points to the same address as `num+1`. You can check this short code to see what is happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num[3][2]={ {00,01},{10,11},{20,21} }; 
    int (*fp)[2] = num+1;
    int* fpp = *(num+1);
    printf("%d\n", (void*)fpp == (void*)fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 1 - those pointers hold the same memory address.

Comment: Thanks that code diagram helped me understand your post.

Answer (score 0):

*But, why both `*(num+i)` and `(num+i)` point to the same address?*

It's because:

1. The array name is a pointer (address) to the first element of the array.
2. `array[x]` equals to `*(array+x)`