# Generate n-Dimensional Arrays on Runtime in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, typedef

I working on a tool that handles netCDF files in C++. I want my tool to be able to handle netCDF files with different layouts. At the moment I am only able to load netCDF files that contain data varaiables with one or three dimensions. I would like to allow n-dimensional netCDF variables. The problem is, that I need to convert the data in to a different format that uses raw C arrays. So I need to be able to generate n-dimensional C arrays on runtime.

I could store the data in a one dimensional array and use different access patterns for the different numbers of dimensions, but I would rather use n-dimensional arrays if possible (They just work a lot better with the format I want to convert to).

I think this should be possible using templates and typedefs but I am not experienced enough with those to implement it by myself without investing serious time learning more about these concepts.

I appreciate any help or idea how to solve this.

Comment: Use `std::vector` maybe?

Comment: *"I need to be able to generate n-dimensional C arrays on runtime....I think this should be possible using templates and typedefs"* -- no. The problem being that to use C arrays in C++ you need to provide a literal-constant for the dimensions as C++ does not support variable-length array declarations (except by compiler extension).

Comment: This answer to [SO: Iterating over an N-dimensional matrix with variable dimension sizes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043309/7478597) might be helpful. Please, note that it stores all data consecutively in `multi_dim_array::data` - a `std::vector` from which you can get the address of the internal C-like array with `std::vector::data()`. Concerning multi-dimensional arrays in C, I found a another answer with a nice sketch: [SO: Using 2D arrays as multiple 1D arrays when using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850802/7478597). (I remembered another which I couldn't find for now.)